# Use an annotation as a typed method parameter

Tags: java, annotations

In Java is it possible to use a class annotation as a typed method parameter.
For example - this is your annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Entity {
}
```

then

```
@Entity
public class Car {
...
}
```

and then do

```
interface Persister {
     void persist(Entity entity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
public @interface Entity {
    String name();
}


public class Car implements Entity{
    public String name(){ return "car"; }
}
```

but that's just odd. `Entity` should be an ordinary interface instead.

### ---

It is possible though that through annotation processing, we can require that an argument to a method must have a static type that contains certain annotation. Not sure if someone has done that.

Comment: But what is Entity only has just a bunch of static properties such as Name etc but has no behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but it won't do what you expect.  This persist(Entity) method can only take your Entity annotation, not an instance of a class you want to use.

Instead what you can do is

```
interface Entity { }

interface Car extends Entity {

interface Persister {
     void persist(Entity entity);
}
```

This will work as expected and you can pass an instance of a Car to the persist method.