# Using annotation as method parameter

Tags: groovy, annotations

This is a similar question to [Use an annotation as a typed method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290784/use-an-annotation-as-a-typed-method-parameter) but this question if for the Groovy programming language.

In Groovy, is it possible to use a class annotation as a typed method parameter. For example - this is your annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Entity {
}
```

then

```
@Entity
public class Car {
...
}
```

and then do

```
interface Persister {
     void persist(Entity entity);
}
```

??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can get an instance of the `Entity` class when you fetch it from some member:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Entity { }


@Entity
class Car { }


def persist(Entity entity) {
  println "entity=$entity"
}


car = new Car()
entity = car.class.getAnnotation(Entity)
persist entity // this will print "entity=@Entity()"
```